# R: Binning Values from One Column Based Upon the Value of Another Column

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following DF:

```
>TEST
$`TEST`
             X      Y
[1,] 343.8986928 100.0000000000
[2,] 344.8980807   1.5791135909
[3,] 344.9029097   0.1523702597
[4,] 344.9049696   1.4031613636
[5,] 345.8944890   8.9483103485
[6,] 345.9029386   0.8219974538
[7,] 346.9007657   0.1255592335
[8,] 347.8902851   0.2001806452
```

I want to add the values of Y for each interval of one in X.

So, I would like 343, 344, 345, 346, 347 to be the bins and used to add Y.

So, for 344, I would add 1.579 + 0.152 + 1.403.

And then output one number for each interval, like this:

100, 3.13, 9.7, 0.12, 0.2

Where 100 == 343, 3.13 == 344, etc.

The numbers in X will vary. Ex., 212, 213, 214, or 112, 113, 114, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the bins by taking a floor.  Then group by and summarize:

```
library(tidyverse)
TEST %>%
mutate(X = floor(X)) %>% 
  group_by(X) %>% 
  summarize(Y = sum(Y))
```

Comment: This would lose the original values of X. If you want to keep them, it would be better to save `floor(X)` as a new variable and group on that.

Comment: You will lose the original `X` anyways with `summarize()`